# Artisan says database not found

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm working on a brand new laravel application for learning laravel.

I've done the following (I'm following [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-react-app-with-laravel-restful-backend-part-1-laravel-5-api--cms-29442)):

1. Created new application using `laravel new test_project_2`
2. Setup the .env file
3. Created a database called `laravel`
4. Run php artisan migrate

This is my .env file:
[image]

This is what I get:
[image]

As you can see, I can use the "laravel" database perfectly well when I'm logged into Mariadb via terminal. The website also renders absolutely fine. I did run the SQL command - `SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'` but I got the message `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'laravel' in 'where clause'`

Note - I've worked on other dummy laravel projects last week and didn't face any problems, although admittedly I'm not sure if I ran the php artisan migrate command for those (wasn't required, but I might have run it just cause I kept seeing it).

- Why is this problem happening?
- How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by changing the `DB_HOST` values from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`.

Anyone know why this works? Beats the heck out of me.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command and try migrate command

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try creating your database with below and then try migration.

```
mysql -u root -p

create database [DB name]; 

use [DB name];
```

Then do migration:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Also make sure you have entered correct database name & credential.